# How to use Play to return 415 unsupported media type?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

It seems that Play 1.x had this functionality, but I can't find an example in the 2.x documentation. Is there a way to configure a controller to return a 415 if `accepts` or `content-type` doesn't match? I can do it manually in the controller like this:

```
// for GET, POST, PUT, etc.
if (!request().accepts(Http.MimeTypes.JSON)) {
    return new StatusHeader(UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
}
// for POST, PUT, PATCH, etc.
if (!request().contentType().orElse("").equals(Http.MimeTypes.JSON)) {
    return new StatusHeader(UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
}
```

But it seems like this is something that should be supported by the framework w/o having to use that block of code in every controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 2.5.x does provide support for doing this.

Apologies that my example is in Scala, but you can achieve just the same with the Java API - just check the docs below.

```
// Scala example

def accept = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    render {
      case Accepts.Json() => Ok(Json.parse("""{"message" : "Thanks for sending and accepting JSON"}"""))
    }
  }
```

By specifying that you are using an explicit `parse.json` body parser, Play will automatically build a result with  a `415` code for you if the client attempts to send anything other than `application/json` for the Content-Type. See [the Java examples](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers#Choosing-an-explicit-body-parser) that covers this bit.

The `case Accepts.Json()` is an extractor that tests that the media type is within range (ie. `application/json` in your use case). If the client sends a different media type then I think Play builds a `406 Not Acceptable`. See [the Java examples](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaContentNegotiation#Content).

Comment: Thanks. I swear I looked at the docs but somehow still missed this.